# javafx moving FXML properties to a separateclass / bean

Tags: spring, javafx, javabeans

I've got a simple app that has its elements defined in .FXML file

```
<TextField fx:id="httpsPort" promptText="text1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
<TextField fx:id="adminPort" promptText="text2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
```

so far I was doing this

```
public class Controller {
    public TextField httpsPort;
    public TextField adminPort;

    //getters and setters here
}
```

but I'd like to be doing this in the controller

```
public class Controller {

    //maybe some magic annotation here
    public Layout layout;

    //the rest of the code
}


public class Layout {

    public TextField httpsPort;
    public TextField adminPort;

}
```

so basically, I'd like to separate properties that are connected to layout to another class either using some annotation, xml configuration, etc.. Is there any known way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the purpose of separating out the controlled fields from the controller?

Comment: cleaner code I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`<fx:include>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements):

ports.fxml:

```xml
<GridPane fx:controller="com.mycompany.Layout">

    <TextField fx:id="httpsPort" promptText="text1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
    <TextField fx:id="adminPort" promptText="text2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />

</GridPane>
```

and then main.fxml:

```xml
< ... fx:controller="com.mycompany.MainController">
    <!-- ... -->
    <fx:include fx:id="layout" source="ports.fxml"/>
    <!-- ... -->
```

Your `MainController` can do:

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private Layout layoutController ; // field name is fx:id with "Controller" appended

}
```

and the `Layout` is

```
public class Layout {

    @FXML
    private TextField httpsPort;
    @FXML
    private TextField adminPort;

}
```

See the documentation section on [Nested Controllers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers) (or dozens of similar questions on this site) for more details.

Comment: awesome! Thanks. gonna give this a shot!

Comment: can I keep the actions in the main controller?

Comment: @AdamNovakovi If you mean defining an `onAction="..."` on the text field, that always resolves to a method in the controller for that actual FMXL file. So the text field action would have to be in the `Layout` controller, which is what basic encapsulation would dictate you should do anyway. In other words, if you are going to "modularize" the FXML, you modularize the FXML and the controller together.

Comment: thanks! so basically, I should be trying to separate fxml fields and controllers? I wanted to keep my logic in one controller but fields declarations (along with lots of getter / setter methods) away from that controller

Comment: @AdamNovakovi What would be the point of declaring the fields in one controller if you don't have any logic there associated with them? And what getter and setter methods are you referring to?

Comment: just wanted to separate declaration and getters and setters so the result would look like this

public Layout layout;

//some actionMethod
String result = "something";
layout.getHttpPort().setText(result);

Comment: well each FXML field should have its getter and setter if I want to keep the fields private (i didn't put it into question above) ..at least, that's what I read. Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: Yeah that's completely wrong. You should never expose the controls outside the controller. Keep them private and don't include any getters or setters. It's a design error to access the UI components anywhere else in your application.

Comment: just have to correct something. Fields must be public but don't require getters/setters

Comment: @AdamNovakovi Again, fields should be private (pretty much always, but definitely here). If you make the controls accessible outside the controller then they become part of the controller's public API. That means you can never change them, e.g. you can never replace a `TextField` with a `ComboBox` or a `TextArea`, because you would break other parts of your application. You render your entire application unmaintainable if you do that.